# Field extension degree theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Calculating the degree of this extension $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt2):\mathbb Q]=n $

With the irreducible polynomials I know:

$[\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}):\mathbb Q]=3$, $[\mathbb Q(\sqrt2):\mathbb Q]=2.$

So $2|n$ and $3|n$ that means $n\geq6.$

On the other hand $n\leq2\times3=6.$ So $n$ must be $6.$

---

What I want to know is what result or theorem is applied here for doing this last part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L,K$ be finite field extensions of a field $k$, with $[L:k]=l$ and $[K:k]=k$. Then $[LK:k]\leq [L:k]\cdot [K:k]$. In particular, if $(l,k)=1$, then $[LK:k]=l \cdot k$

In your case $k=\mathbb{Q}$,$L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, $l=3$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $k=2$, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=6$.

Comment: why is that? can you post the proof?

Comment: It's a standard proof when you study field extensions. You can find it in any book about it, you have to look for degree of the compositum of fields

Comment: found it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that  $\sqrt[3]{2}$ satisfies $x^3- 2$ over $\mathbb Q (\sqrt 2)$. Hence $[\mathbb Q (\sqrt[3] 2):\mathbb Q (\sqrt 2)]$ is at most $3$.